# Array search dont know search

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

i have this array:

```
include("config.php");
$start = "2014-06-20 08:00:00";
$data = mysql_query ("select * from evenement WHERE start = '$start'");
$zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data);
while($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data))
{
 $arr2[] = $zaznam["resourceId"];   //store query values in second array

}
```

If i echo $arr2 i get this:

```
Array ( [0] => STK1 )
```

now i make condition for array_search:

```
if (array_search('STK1', $arr2)) {
    echo "Arr2 contains STK1 <br>";
}
else {
    echo "Arr2 not contains STK1 <br>";
}
```

**but** i get this **Arr2 not contains STK1**
how it is possible? What im doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, if there is an answer that actually answers your question, you should choose one accepting it. This will give reputation points to you and to those who tried to help you... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is totally correct behaviour for PHP.

The documention for the return value says:

`Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.`

In your case you are getting 0 which also evaluates to false in an if.

You have to check if the value is not false using the  `!==` operator.

```
if (array_search('STK1', $arr2) !== false) {
    echo "Arr2 contains STK1 <br>";
}
else {
    echo "Arr2 not contains STK1 <br>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i got it before you answer. But thank you for check my minds!

Answer (score 1):

From the [array_search documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-search.php):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

`array_search` is returning 0 because it found a match at index 0 of the array. This is evaluating to false.

Instead try:

```
if (array_search('STK1', $arr2) !== false) {
    echo "Arr2 contains STK1 <br>";
}
else {
    echo "Arr2 not contains STK1 <br>";
}
```